# Jquery Live DataAttribute

Tags: jquery, html

I have a code like this,

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Sidebar</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <i class="open-icon" data-open="false"></i>
    <div class="contact-form-ch">
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="content-1"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(".open-icon").on("click", function () {
            var statu = $(this).data("open");

            if (statu) {
                $(".contact-form-ch").animate({ "width": "700px" });
                $("body").animate({ "margin": "0" });
                $(this).removeAttr("data-open").attr("data-open", false);
            } else {
                $(".contact-form-ch").animate({ "width": "700px" });
                $("body").animate({ "margin": "0 -350px 0 350px" });
                $(this).removeAttr("data-open").attr("data-open", true);
            }

        });

    </script>
</body>
```

When I run the first this project. this code return **false**

```
var statu = $(this).data("open");
```

That's ok, because, `data-open="false"`

But when I click `<i class="open-icon" data-open="false"></i>` data-open will be replace with **true** So, would be `<i class="open-icon" data-open="true"></i>`

But `var statu` still and always return **false**. But It must be **true** on runtime.
How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".open-icon").on("click", function () {
            var statu = $(this).data("open");

            if (statu) {
                $(".contact-form-ch").animate({ "width": "700px" });
                $("body").animate({ "margin": "0" });
                $(this).data("open", false);
            } else {
                $(".contact-form-ch").animate({ "width": "700px" });
                $("body").animate({ "margin": "0 -350px 0 350px" });
                $(this).data("open", true);
            }

        });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4tj29v7y/1/)

Answer (score 4):

You simply need to use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data1)

```
 $(this).data("open", true/false); //Set value using data
```

instead of

```
 $(this).removeAttr("data-open").attr("data-open", true/false)
```

A Good Read for you: [jQuery Data vs Attr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr)